# Spring Service Activator - Can we use same method with ref for two different input channel in Java?

Tags: java, xml, spring, java-8, spring-integration

we have a generic code to execute the same logic but input channel will be different. See for an example

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="exampleChannel_1" ref="somePojo" method="someMethod"/>
<int:service-activator input-channel="exampleChannel_2" ref="somePojo" method="someMethod"/>
```

Can we use like this ? Should i make someMethod as Synchronized one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. As for synchronization it depends on the actual implementation of your service activator and if there are any concurrency issues. We can't answer that question without seeing it. In any event, the synchronization question is not related to spring-integration.

Comment: If you synchronize the entire method you will single-thread. If you use selective synchronization and `Atomic*` variables it might be ok. It's better to make your method thread-safe. If you can't you could consider putting `somePojo` in `prototype` scope so that each activator gets its own service instance.

Comment: Another way is to have only one `int:service-activator` for that method, but `<bridge>` another channel to that one configured on the service activator. The thread-safety is fully not related to the question. If with a single service activator you may face race condition issue from different messages if your service is not stateless.